# Why "All Store View" option is hide from store select box , if single website is present for admin section?

Tags: admin, adminhtml, multistore, programmatically, stores

I am working one website - many stores magento setup, i assign one website to sub admin and detect "All Store View" is hide in that case.Why this option is hide from select box?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If the admin user has only access to one website, he should not be able to change global values. Makes sense to me.

Comment: I want it display in every case, is it possible?

Comment: Are you using Enterprise?

Comment: I am using 1.9.2 magento version.

Comment: Then you are using an extension for this and I can't give you any advise. Permissions per website is a Magento Enterprise feature.